# Keras model with two inputs given to the same layers, trained on one of the inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

[Here's a diagram of what I need to create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CrG7.jpg)

Basically, I want to make a model that takes two inputs (in1 and in2), both inputs are given to the layers **l1** and **l2**, **l2** gives the outputs **out1** and **out2**, but the layers are only trained on **in1**. In other words, the network can be viewed as **in1** -> **l1** -> **l2** -> **out1**, and I want to be able to get the output of this network for another input *during its creation*.

Here's what I've tried :

```
in1 = Input(shape=(x,), name="input")
in2 = Input(shape=(x,), name="input2")
l1 = Dense(x, activation="relu", name="l1")(in1)
l2 = Dense(x, activation="relu", name="l1")(l1)
out1 = Dense(x, activation="sigmoid", name="out1")(l2)

model1 = Model(inputs = first, outputs = out1)
model1.compile(optimizer = "Adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics = "accuracy")
model2 = Model(inputs = model1.get_layer("input2").output, outputs = model1.get_layer("out1").output)
```

But obviously, model2 doesn't know that input2 exists ("No such layer: input2"). I also tried adding in2 as input and output of model1, and many other combinations of inputs / outputs, but pretty much everything gives a graph disconnected error, and I'm running out of ideas.

In case you find another optimized way to do it, what I want in the end is to concatenate the two outputs and compute a new final output, something like that:

```
conc = Concatenate()([out1, out2])
final_out = Dense(x, activation="sigmoid", name="outfinal")(conc)
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit for clarification:

I need to solve a multi-label classification task; my model takes a vector **v[t]** as input. The goal of all of this, in the end, is to see wether having the output of the last layer at **t-1** helps the network in its task at **t** - that's why I want to train the model on **v[t]** at each step, but I also need **v[t-1]** and its output by the model to reinject it at the end.

Comment: so it is going to be a model inside another model? the input of your final model would be inp1, inp2 and the output would be final_out? the input/output of the inside model would be inp1 and out1?

Comment: @SoheilStar Yes you can see it that way, as a model inside another model. To be more precise, I want to train both models at the same time, and only on inp1 for the shared layers 1 and 2, except that the final model will have the prediction of the inner model on inp2 to (hopefully) improve its result.

Comment: okay, so I suggest you write a costume training loop for your models. in this loop you would first pass inp1 to model1 and train the weights. then you freeze the weights of model1 and then pass inp1, inp2 to train model2. you also need to modify the way you defined your models which is not correct.

Comment: Do you need both the inputs? Also, are you providing both inputs on training the model, but you need that `l1` and `l2` should be trained either on `in1` or `in2`?

Comment: @SoheilStar Thank you for your solution, I had thought of doing something like that but I hoped there'd be a way to do it directly in the definition of the model. I'll do it that way.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I edited my question, hope it makes it more clear.